# Converting Text Date to Date VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date cell value which was extracted in this format `20220610`. Is it possible to convert this to a date format e.g., `10 Jun 2022`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need VBA. Try below formula-

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2)), "dd mmm yyyy")
```

If you need `VBA` then try below function. You have to format resulting cell as proper date format or use `TEXT()` function.

```
Function MyDate(iDate As String) As Date
    MyDate = DateSerial(Left(iDate, 2), Mid(iDate, 5, 2), Right(iDate, 2))
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I would always advocate to convert the string into a real date value and set the date format of the cell rather than convert the date back to a string

Comment: @FunThomas I also suggest that. Then we can use either cell formatting or `TEXT()` function to convert required format.

Comment: @Harun24hr Definitely use cell formatting (number format) to get the desired format. The moment you use `TEXT()` it is not a date anymore and useless to Excel. Excel just sees a string then and cannot calculate with it. You want to avoid that at any cost and keep it a numeric date.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, that is correct. Many novice user do not notice it. When they get date as number value, they get confused. In that case `TEXT()` may help.